# Word smartart realization with HTML/CSS/JavaScript (geometric shapes)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ms-word

I'm sure there are a lot of you knowing the following element created as "smart art" with Microsoft Word:

[image: Word smartart]

Is there any framework for web realization of this graphic (pure HTML, CSS, JavaScript)? Or can you imagine how this could be realized as a "clean" web element?

Comment: Have you considered SVG?

Comment: D3.js check out d3js.org

Comment: According SVG: This would be a picture format, right? Well, I basically want an HTML-based approach. According D3.js: I know this source. But I didn't find any element similar to the one I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea on how to do it with pure html. You can wrap this concept into a snazzy javascript function to speed things up. The idea is simple border-radius circles:

NOTE: only tested on chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/9m6fbtxL/

```
.circle1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    height: 340px;
    border-radius: 170px;
    border: 1px solid #4e82bc;
    background-color: #4e82bc;
}

.circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 110px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4e82bc;
}

.circle3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 212px;
    left: 120px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4e82bc;
}

.textArea1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 8px;
    left: 170px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #4e82bc;
}

.textArea2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 110px;
    left: 170px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #4e82bc;
}

.textArea3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 212px;
    left: 170px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #4e82bc;
}

.textArea4 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 16px;
    top: 314px;
    left: 170px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #4e82bc;
}

.textArea5 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 14px;
    top: 332px;
    left: 170px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #4e82bc;
}
```

Comment: The idea of SmartArt is that if you add text, it gets auto-formatted to fit into the shapes and all texts get the same font size at the same time. I cannot see this here.

Comment: He was interested in receiving direction toward realizing the graphic with web elements not the full smart art concept. I gave enough information to realize the graphic, the 'smarts' can be programmed by making the values dynamic with JS. If you are wanting more detailed 'smarts' you can make another question for it which I would be happy to answer if you ping me about it :)